# Link in media services to blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

The "Assets" Blade from "Media Services" has a column with an "Blob Storage" link. I assume this should go to the blob in storage, so one can download the asset. However, this link does not work - it gives a 404 for all assets that i tried.

Does anyone know how to make these links work (or, otherwise, how to download an asset without manually resolving the uuid?)

Answer (score 0):

I think why your resource is 404 is you dont have the Authority.

Please go the the container that you shore the media files and have a check of the access tier:

[image]

Change it to container tier.

Comment: I just did change the access level to "container". following the link still gives me a 404. (Also, isn't this access level thing about public (anonymous) access? i am accessing this while beeing logged into my account which absolutely does have access to this resources.)